# How to get status code from the server in android using volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I need to get the status code from a restful api after making a request from android and update my UI according to the status response. I am using android volley to make requests.

I have initialized a member variable and initialized with 0 in the onCreate method.

`private int deleteStatus`

Here is a method that handles the delete from the api and updates the `deleteStatus` variable.

```
    public int handleDeletePet(int petId) {

        String url = "myurl";

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, url + petId, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                if(response != null) {
                    deleteStatus = response.statusCode;
                }
                Log.i("deleted status : ", String.valueOf(deleteStatus));

                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }

        };
        MySingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(this.getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);

        Log.i("status before returning : ", String.valueOf(deleteStatus));
        return deleteStatus;
    }
```

Here is where I get the int value returned from the above `handleDeletePet` method and try to perform UI updates as necessary.

```
int returnedDeleteStatus = handleDeletePet(currentPet.getPetId());
Log.i("returned status ", String.valueOf(returnedDeleteStatus));
if (returnedDeleteStatus == 200) {
    myPetsList.remove(currentPet);
    myPetsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    Snackbar.make(myPetsRecyclerView, "Deleted Pet " + currentPet.getPetName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
            Snackbar.make(myPetsRecyclerView, "Cannot delete " + currentPet.getPetName() + " since it has events", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            myPetsAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
```

This is what the log shows for the values of the status reponse

```
I/status before returning :: 0
I/returned status: 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9c0850c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9c0830e0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9c0850c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9c0830e0)
I/deleted status :: 200
```

The value is shown correctly only inside the `parseNetworkResponse` and when I return it even with a correct delete activity, it shows 0 outside of it. Also, the order in which the log prints is weird. First, it should print `delete status`, then `status before returning :` then `returned status`. But it prints in wrong order as above. Could this be because it takes time to return the value from the server? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The logs are not printing in the wrong order, you are correct that it takes time to return the value from the server.  A simple way to ensure that you have this response code value for your UI would be to create your own interface / callback to handle the server response.  Then pass an instance of this interface to your method that makes the network call, handling the response through this instance.  The interface could look like this:

```
   public interface GenericCallback {
    /**
     * return your response code, or any other data you need here
     * or in any number of methods you wish to implement
     */
    default String onServerCodeResponse(String response) {
        return response;
    }
}
```

Then you would change your method to accept an instance of this callback / interface:

```
public int handleDeletePet(int petId, GenericCallback callback) {

    String url = "myurl";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, url + petId, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            if (response != null) {
                deleteStatus = response.statusCode;
            }
            Log.i("deleted status : ", String.valueOf(deleteStatus));
            //return the code through your callback / interface instance
            callback.onServerCodeResponse(deleteStatus);
                    
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }

    };
    MySingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(this.getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);

    Log.i("status before returning : ", String.valueOf(deleteStatus));
    return deleteStatus;
}
```

Now when calling this function, you can either create an instance of GenericCallback first, and pass to the method or create on the fly like this:

```
handleDeletePet(1, new GenericCallback() {
        @Override
        public String onServerCodeResponse(String response) {
            //you now have the code here, update your UI
            updateUiFunction(response);
            return null;
        }
    });
```